# Industry Standard for API Authentication on MEAN Stack

Tags: json, api, authentication, mean-stack, credentials

What tends to be the industry standard for API authentication? I'm looking at implementing an API for CRUD on a member management system and need authentication. I came across [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens) article using JSON web tokens. I've also seen tutorials that mention using session based authentication, as does this one.

**What is the industry standard for authentication of users to API access?**

**EDIT:**
Is [this article](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/) explaining tokens vs session based still relevant? It's over two years old.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that OAuth 2.0 has taken over as the dominant API credential in use, but it's far from the simplest option.